# iphone question about importing header when sending data between classes

Tags: iphone, class, import, header-files

Im sending data from one class to another, Its working but I have a question, I noticed that if I

> #import "receiver.h"

class in the sender.h or sender.m works either way,

so what is the preffered correct place to import my receiver class? in the *.h or in the *.m??

tnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import it in the .m

You should only import a file in the header if it refers to something it declares. If the header only refers to a pointer then you can use a forward declaration in the header and import it in the .m

Answer (score -2):

I'd recommend the .m file.

Comment: If it's not needed in the .h it shouldn't be imported there. You're just adding dependencies needlessly.

Comment: This is not correct, and it will lead to code being copied to where it is not required. Forward declaration is used in this case.